"CString not terminated" when using LLDB-MI with Visual Studio Code on Windows ARM64
I recently switched to an ARM64 machine with the Snapdragon X Elite on Windows and I am trying to set up Visual Studio Code. Since MinGW-w64 with gcc and gdb isn’t available for ARM64, I’m using LLVM-Mingw (version 18.1.18).(I also tried MSVC but I just cannot get used to it).
The problem arises when I try to start lldb-mi from within VS Code. I encounter the following error (full output at the bottom of the question):
[Error] MI parsing error: CString not terminated: ""C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"
[Error] MI parsing error: Result expected: "path="C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"
[Error] MI parsing error: trailing chars: ""C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"


The Launch Configuration (launch.json):
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "showDisplayString": true,
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true
            },
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}

Debugging using only lldb directly via CLI works fine.
I also tried the vs code extension CodeLLDB but unfortunately that one is not available on ARM64 yet.
For anyone who would like to reproduce the problem.
The code is a simple Hello World program in C++ and CMake used:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(TestProject)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

add_executable(testProject ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(  testProject)


Environment:

Visual Studio Code version: 1.91.0 (user setup)
Clang revision: 3b5b5c1ec4a3095ab096dd780e84d7ab81f3d7ff
LLVM revision: 3b5b5c1ec4a3095ab096dd780e84d7ab81f3d7ff

Any idea what I am missing?
Update based on Electro Organic's suggestion:
I updated the launch.json with absolute path. I also move it into a path without an underscore, same issue persist. I also tried forward and double backwards slash, no change.
I checked with notepad++ for any hidden symbols but couldn't find one either.
New launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\Users\\Public\\TestProject\\build\\testProject.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Public\\TestProject",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\BuildTools\\llvm-mingw-20240619-ucrt-aarch64\\bin\\lldb-mi.exe"
        }
    ]
}

Full Debug output:
1: (80) LaunchOptions{"name":"(lldb) Launch","type":"cppdbg","request":"launch","program":"C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject\\build\\testProject.exe","showDisplayString":true,"args":[],"stopAtEntry":false,"cwd":"C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject","logging":{"engineLogging":true},"externalConsole":true,"MIMode":"lldb","__configurationTarget":6,"__sessionId":"b05ff7d2-9d7c-4e88-96b2-79ee5c80f421","miDebuggerPath":null}
1: (131) Starting: "C:\BuildTools\llvm-mingw-20240619-ucrt-aarch64\bin\lldb-mi.exe" --interpreter=mi
1: (201) DebuggerPid=21952
1: (806) ->(gdb)
1: (816) <-1001-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
1: (816) ->1001^done
1: (817) ->(gdb)
1: (819) 1001: elapsed time 3
1: (820) <-1002-gdb-set solib-search-path "C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject\\build;"
1: (821) ->1002^done
1: (821) 1002: elapsed time 1
1: (821) <-1003-environment-cd C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject
1: (821) ->(gdb)
1: (821) ->1003^done,path="C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject
1: (821) ->"
1: (821) ->(gdb)
[Error] 1: (825) MI parsing error: CString not terminated: ""C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"
[Error] 1: (825) MI parsing error: Result expected: "path="C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"
[Error] 1: (825) MI parsing error: trailing chars: ""C:\\Users\\User_\\Documents\\Development\\TestProject"
[Error] 1: (894) EXCEPTION:
[Error] 1: (895) EXCEPTION:    at MICore.MIResults.ParseResultList(Span listStr, ResultClass resultClass)
[Error] 1: (895) EXCEPTION:    at MICore.MIResults.ParseCommandOutput(String output)
[Error] 1: (895) EXCEPTION:    at MICore.Debugger.ProcessStdOutLine(String line)
[Error] 1: (895) EXCEPTION:    at Microsoft.MIDebugEngine.DebuggedProcess.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.<ScheduleStdOutProcessing>b__0()
[Error] 1: (895) EXCEPTION:    at Microsoft.MIDebugEngine.WorkerThread.ThreadFunc()
1: (897) Send Event AD7MessageEvent
[Error] 1: (898) MI parsing error: CString not terminated: """


CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR in your add_executable is probably redundant

This looks like a bug in the LLVM MIMode. The path is being sent with a new line before the closing quote, which breaks the parser.

I kind of solved the problem, while I was unable to find a solution to the original problem, I found out about lldb-dap (previously lldb-vscode) while researching. lldb-dap also allows to debug using vs code but via a different interface.
That does the trick for me to be able to debug using vs code.
I needed to install the lldb-dap extension and the following is my launch.json:
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "lldb-dap",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

        }
      ]
   }

Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

I haven't found a fix to this, but I have made some progress toward the root cause that I want to leave here for future readers.
By trying different values for the "cwd" launch configuration parameter, you can see that the error occurs when the MIEngine tries to apply the "cwd" by sending the environment-cd command to llvm-mi.
I then added the following to the launch configuration:
"miDebuggerArgs": "--log --log-dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\${env:USERNAME}\\\\Documents",

This enables the creation of a log file for each run from lldb-mi's perspective. (The backslashes in log-dir needs to be double-escaped because it gets passed through a command shell once on the way to being executed. That's why I have hard-coded it instead of using something like ${workspaceFolder}.)
What I find is that, in that log file, lines representing commands from MIEngine are CRLF-terminated, but lines generated by llvm-mi are only LF-terminated. That doesn't cause any obvious problems until we get to this exchange:
F,26/08/24 13:14:31,1003-environment-cd C:\\Users\\VBoxUser\\Documents\\cortex-r-template<CR><LF>
F,26/08/24 13:14:31,1003^done,path="C:\\Users\\VBoxUser\\Documents\\cortex-r-template<CR>"<LF>

What this looks like to me is that llvm-mi is reading the environment-cd command and treating the <CR> as part of the command, not part of the line break. Then it echoes that wrong path back in the done,path= response, and MIEngine interprets that  as an end-of-line and complains about "CString not terminated". In the VSCode debug console with "logging": { "engineLogging": true, }, we can even see it try to parse the closing quote as a separate command at the end after it's done reporting the first error:
[Error] 1: (738) MI parsing error: CString not terminated: """

My guess here is that whatever work-arounds the MSys2 runtime has for line ending differences between POSIX and Windows, it's not working correctly (or making things worse) between MIEngine and lldb-mi.

I reported this to lldb-mi
https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi/issues/119
